# python-docx change 'Authors' meta-data

Tags: python-2.7, python-docx

So, I've created a document with python-docx, and everything works as I'd expected, but the 'Authors' are shows as 'Cisco Employee'.

I've tried Googling 'python-docx change author', and other variations, but I can't find anything.

Does an option exist to change the authors name, or is that not possible currently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm, good to know. That's a bit of a bug. I'll get that fixed up :)

In the meantime, you can create a template of your own and customize it to your needs.

Make sure you study this page in the documentation:
http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/documents.html

Basically what you do is:

```
document = Document()
document.save('my-new-template.docx')
```

Then change 'my-new-template.docx' directly, using Word, to have the settings you want, and change your code to start like this:

```
document = Document('my-new-template.docx')
...
```

The changes you made to my-new-template will be reflected in all documents created that way.

Longer term, perhaps soon, there will be a Document.core_props property that will provide access to a CoreProperties object. That object will allow you to set the author and other fields to whatever you want.

**UPDATE**

I added core properties support to `python-docx`, here's how you would use it:

```
document = Document()
core_properties = document.core_properties
core_properties.author = 'Foo B. Baz'
document.save('new-filename.docx')
```

Details about the available properties are in the documentation here:
http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/document.html#coreproperties-objects

Comment: I just pushed v0.7.6 which supports read/write core properties: http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/document.html#coreproperties-objects

Comment: Sorry - but I don't understand how to use this! I've updated to the new version, and I thought `docx.opc.coreprops.CoreProperties.author == 'test'` would work - but this doesn't work. I'd be grateful if you could help :)

Comment: Thanks :) Great module btw!

Comment: Is there any way to add additional custom properties? Sort of like Sharepoint metadata.

Comment: Or, alternatively, is there a way to get access to the content of a custom XML mapping? (the customXML folder in the docx archive: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrriThs7m1s )